# VPS Cron and other email going to spam folder

Tags: cron, sendmail

I have a new vps and I need to setup some cron jobs on it to notify me of what's happening on the server.
I've tested with sendmail and emails are indeed leaving the server, but on my email they are arriving as spam. What are the steps I need to do to configure the box propperly? Its a fresh VPS with Scientific Linux installed.
Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

I might add that from other vps I have the mail goes to the inbox directly.
Also This is from a subdomain I own that is pointing to another server on a A Record.

Edit: Here are the SPF Records already created:

```
Delivered-To: mypersonalEmail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.184.100 with SMTP id et4csp1203226ldc;
        Sun, 24 May 2015 14:44:42 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.180.101.3 with SMTP id fc3mr25461787wib.47.1432503882045;
        Sun, 24 May 2015 14:44:42 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <root@server.rjmarques.com>
Received: from server.rjmarques.com ([1.123.123.1])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dx2si9334561wib.2.2015.05.24.14.44.41
        for <mypersonalEmail@gmail.com>;
        Sun, 24 May 2015 14:44:41 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@server.rjmarques.com designates 1.123.123.1 as permitted sender) client-ip=1.123.123.1;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@server.rjmarques.com designates 1.123.123.1 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=root@server.rjmarques.com
Received: by server.rjmarques.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 2A498528D; Sun, 24 May 2015 21:44:41 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Sun, 24 May 2015 21:44:41 +0000
To: mypersonalEmail@gmail.com, to@server.rjmarques.com
Subject: Test
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20150524214441.2A498528D@server.rjmarques.com>
From: root@server.rjmarques.com (root)

This is a test
```

And the spf record:

```
v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:1.123.123.1 ~all
```

Comment: What's the email provider you're using to receive the mail? You may get some more detail from the message headers

Comment: @GMambaG I've added the Email I got in Email in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Where to look:

- Check the source (headers) of the email for indications of why it was marked as spam
- If your email server did not add any headers (like google) check the email servers spam policy ([google spam policy](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126).
- [Check your IP](http://mxtoolbox.com/supertool.aspx) on blacklists

Common options:

- Check or add a DNS TXT SPF permitting mail from that IP.
- DNS PTR record for your IP and MTA that matches an A record.
- email with a filter to whitelist your address(email/ip/domain)
- Add the From address to your contacts list.
- DKIM
- DMARC
- Use the "Not Spam" button for learning algorithms (thunderbird,gmail,etc)

Comment: I have added the Email Source on the original post and I can't find why it has ben set as spam.

Comment: @ddrjm yah Google won't add headers for reasons only known to them but they do provide a guide. (see link in address)

Comment: @ddrjm note that server.rjmarques.com is not registered in the DNS so that may be why.

Comment: How can you tell that it isn't registered in the dns? Can you point out the specific line? Thanks

Comment: @ddrjm dig server.rjmarques.com = answer:0